# WCF Client Certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, client-certificates, webhttpbinding, ssl-client-authentication

WCF service is configured for client certificate with `X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom` and a custom `X509CertificateValidator`.

Binding is `WebHttpBinding` with `WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport` and `HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate`.

This setup enforces the client to provide a certificate attached to the request and its working fine with requests which has the certificate.

Now, I need to process requests which don't have a certificate attached and let them proceed based on some other conditions. but as I've noted it respond `403` before hitting my custom `X509CertificateValidator`.

How do I hook into WCF requests come without a certificate?

Comment: Did you try to implement `IDispatchMessageInspector` and see if you are able to capture requests without a certificate?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani  yes, I have a few `IDispatchMessageInspector`s. but it doesn't hit even `AfterReceiveRequest`

Comment: @Johnny, `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is not called for client certificate validation if I'm correct. I've tried it anyway but yes. It doesn't hit on `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

Comment: Which `binding` are you using? Could changing of the `SecurityMode` help...to try to avoid transport-level security...